# How to send a file attached to the signature request email

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I'm using the PHP SDK to integrate DocuSign eSign REST API into a Laravel application.
We have been asked to attach a couple of PDF files to every signature request email, but I don't know if this is even possible.

I thought that the [EnvelopeAttachments resource](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeattachments/) would be a way to go, but signers do not receive any attachment so far and [here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/documents/attachments/) it is said that such attachments are not visible for them.

Here there is the SDK code I am using:

```
$attachments = [
            new Attachment([
                'access_control' => 'sender',
                'attachment_id' => '1',
                'attachment_type' => '.pdf',
                'data' => base64_encode($this->getPdf($document, $signers)),
                'label' => 'attachment 1',
                'name' => 'attachment 1',
                'remote_url' => 'attachment 1',
            ]),
        ];
        $envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
            'composite_templates' => $composite_templates,
            'email_subject' => "Firmar $documentTypeSp",
            // 'email_blurb' => "Se solicita su firma para el contrato $document->name",
            'status' => "sent",
            'attachments' => $attachments,
        ]);
        $envelope_definition->setEnvelopeAttachments($attachments);
        return $envelope_definition;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach a file to this email that is auto-generated by the system.
The envelope attachment shows in the envelope, it is not attached to the email.

While I don't recommend it, your only option is to send emails yourself, with links going to your own webserver, where you generate embedded signing URLs on the fly and redirect the users.

I would suggest you consider an alternative to having the attachment in the email. Like having a link in the email that goes to some sort of cloud storage or to your own server.